# Parametrizing a straight line contour for a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Am I on the right track to use the weighted average of $(1-t)z_0 +tz_1$ to parametrize the contour, where $z_0$ is the first point and $z_1$ is the second point?

Then are the bounds the two points or $\infty$ to $-\infty$?

Comment: yes. Do that and say the answer.

Comment: so z(t)=(1-t)(1+3i) +t(5-2i) and dz/dt=4-5i. So im integrating Re(z(t)) x (4-5i) dt which is (4t+1)(4-5i) dt is that correct?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: What are the bounds?

Comment: $0\leq t\leq 1$

Comment: Is that the case for any straight line parametrisation? And my result is 12-15i is that the answer?

Comment: your final answer is right and any straight line parametrization may be written in this form.